# Add complicated querys in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, join, nested, where-clause

I have a complicated situation to make a query in Rails, The models look like:

- Route has_many Interests
- Route has_many Days
- Days has_many Points

I have 2 query , One to search Routes by Interest.title (more than one Interest):

```
    joins(:interests).where(interests: { title: interest.split(',')}).group('routes.id').having('count(interests.route_id) = ?', interest.split(',').length)
```

and other to search Routes by Points.title (more than one)

```
    joins(:days => :points).where(days: { points: { place_id: point.split(',')}}).group('routes.id').having('count(routes.id) = ?', point.split(',').length)
```

but my problem is when I try to add both, I use this:

```
    joins(:interests).where(interests: { title: interest.split(',')}).group('routes.id').joins(:days => :points).where(days: { points: { place_id: point.split(',')}}).group('routes.id').having('count(routes.id) = ?', point.split(',').length+interest.split(',').length)
```

But is not working

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Don't work properly

Comment: did you get any error message?
did you get any result?
If you have got result can you post the sql query as well?

Comment: SELECT  "routes".* FROM "routes" INNER JOIN "interests" ON "interests"."route_id" = "routes"."id" INNER JOIN "days" ON "days"."route_id" = "routes"."id" INNER JOIN "points" ON "points"."day_id" = "days"."id" WHERE "routes"."place_id" = $1 AND "interests"."title" IN ('interest2', 'interest1') AND "points"."place_id" IN ('ChIJawXFQIQOZ0gRoucFdZIzGbM4', 'ChIJawXFQIQOZ0gRoucFdZIzGbM6', 'ChIJawXFQIQOZ0gRoucFdZIzGbM5', 'ChIJawXFQIQOZ0gRoucFdZIzGbM7') GROUP BY routes.id HAVING (count(routes.id) = 6)